# In Golang web application development, is it possible to use Go's template with the jade (pug) template engine?

Tags: go, web-applications, pug, template-engine

I'm developing Go web application and using Go's built-in template. I can use `Emmet` to quickly generate HTML code snippets. However, I do prefer the succinct [`jade` template engine](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) (renamed to pug recently). I want to know if it possible to use `jade (pug)` with Go and how to set it up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're looking to this https://github.com/Joker/jade ?

Answer (score 0):

The hard way would be to have a separated nodejs process to compile the template on the go. The easy way would be, like [@Mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6452829/mario-alexandro-santini) said, to use a golang implementation of jade engine.

Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/Joker/jade) and the [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/Joker/jade).